# pyspark python recursive join x-level

Tags: python, performance, recursion, pyspark

As input I have two datasets:
One with items I need to evaluate (item, issue, type) and a second one with the relations between fathers and childs (~18mio rows).

As output I need for each item one row with the full breakdown (amount of levels unknown) as array ([type1-issue1-item1, type2-issue2-item2, ....., type(n)-issue(n)-item(n)])

I tried several approaches without success because of calculation time or missing knowledge/understanding.

My current code is nearly back to first approach with a simple recursive function.
As first step I generate a dataset which contains all fathers for a child in an array column (reduction to 1.8mio rows):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def item_links(all_item_links):
    input = all_item_links.select(
        F.concat_ws(
            ',',
            all_item_links.childtype,
            all_item_links.childissue,
            all_item_links.child
        ).alias("id"),
        all_item_links.child,
        all_item_links.childtype,
        all_item_links.childissue,
        F.concat_ws(
            ',',
            all_item_links.fathertype,
            all_item_links.fatherissue,
            all_item_links.father
        ).alias("father")
    )
    df = input.groupBy(
        input.id,
        input.child,
        input.childtype,
        input.childissue,
    ).agg(
        F.collect_set(input.father).alias("father_array")
    )
    return df
```

the outcome is then used for the recursive function

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def task_cascade(item_links):

    df = item_links.filter(
       (item_links.child == 'item1') & (item_links.childissue == 'A'),
    ).select(
        item_links.child.alias("object"),
        item_links.childissue.alias("object_issue"),
        item_links.childtype.alias("object_type"),
        item_links.id.alias("uid"),
        item_links.father_array.alias("fa")
    )
    df = df.alias("base").join(
        item_links.alias("join"),
        F.array_contains(F.col("base.fa"), F.col("join.id")),
        "inner"
    ).select(
        F.col("base.object"),
        F.col("base.object_issue"),
        F.col("base.object_type"),
        F.col("join.id").alias("uid"),
        F.col("join.father_array").alias("fa"),
        F.array(
            F.concat_ws(
                ',',
                F.col("join.childtype"),
                F.col("join.childissue"),
                F.col("join.child")
            )
        ).alias("all_links")
    )
    return recursive_links(df, item_links, 2)

def recursive_links(df, all_link, max_iter=5):
    link_df = all_link.join(
        df,
        F.array_contains(all_link.father_array, df.uid),
        "inner"
    )
    if (link_df.count() == 0) | (max_iter<=1):
        return df

    df = link_df.select(
        link_df.object,
        link_df.object_issue,
        link_df.object_type,
        link_df.id.alias("uid"),
        link_df.father_array.alias("fa"),
        F.concat(
            F.array(
                F.concat_ws(
                    ',',
                    link_df.childtype,
                    link_df.childissue,
                    link_df.child
                )
            ),
            link_df.all_links
        ).alias("all_links")
    )
    return recursive_links(df, all_link, max_iter-1)
```

Unfortunately this is still taking quite too much time. I stopped the last build after 22h.

Does anyone have a good idea how to improve the performance?

Here the structure of inputs and expected output. There can be up to 30 levels.

```
Item Dataset:
| item | issue | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item3 | AB | subtask |
| item4 | C | task |

Link Dataset:
| child | childissue | childtype | father | fatherissue | fathertype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item2 | A | subtask | item1 | A | task |
| item3 | AB | subtask | item1 | B | task |
| item3 | AB | subtask | item1 | A | task |
| item4 | C | task | item2 | A | subtask |
| item4 | C | task | item1 | A | task |
| item1 | A | task | item5 | A | task |
| item5 | A | task | item6 | A | task |
| item6 | A | task | item7 | A | task |
| item7 | A | task | item8 | A | task |    

Output Dataset
| object | object_issue | object_type | all_links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item4 | C | task | [subtask-A-item2, task-A-item1, task-A-item5, task-A-item6, task-a-item7] |
| item4 | C | task | [task-A-item1, task-A-item5, task-A-item6, task-a-item7] |
| item3 | AB | subtask | [task-B-item1, task-A-item5, task-A-item6, task-a-item7] |
| item3 | AB | subtask | [task-A-item1, task-A-item5, task-A-item6, task-a-item7] |
```

Comment: would u mind share part of ur input df and expected output df

Comment: structure is added

Comment: i'll post my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

the main point is `collect_set`.  I cant reproduce ur Output Dataset due to the lack of info: how are 'Item Dataset' and 'Link Dataset' joined.

```
d1 = [
    ('item2', 'A', 'subtask', 'item1', 'A', 'task'),
    ('item3', 'AB', 'subtask', 'item1', 'B', 'task'),
    ('item3', 'AB', 'subtask', 'item1', 'A', 'task'),
    ('item4', 'C', 'task', 'item2', 'A', 'subtask'),
    ('item4', 'C', 'task', 'item1', 'A', 'task'),
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d1, ['child', 'childissue', 'childtype', 'father', 'fatherissue', 'fathertype'])\
        .withColumn('uid', concat_ws('-', col('fathertype'), col('fatherissue'), col('father')))

df1.groupBy('child', 'childissue', 'childtype')\
    .agg(collect_set(col('uid')).alias('all_links'))\
    .show(10, False)

+-----+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
|child|childissue|childtype|all_links                      |
+-----+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
|item3|AB        |subtask  |[task-A-item1, task-B-item1]   |
|item2|A         |subtask  |[task-A-item1]                 |
|item4|C         |task     |[task-A-item1, subtask-A-item2]|
+-----+----------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: the link dataset contains a lot more entries compared to the item dataset. The item dataset is only used to get an entry point for which items i need the full cascade.

Comment: I edited the sample datasets by hoping it's more understandable now. your code is like my iterim step to reduce the amount of rows by probably having an acceptable calculation time in the final step.